# Having trouble connecting to my database server: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have an error connecting to my database server.

This is my application.properties without the username and password:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://159.65.200.68:3306/timYcreateDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&autoReconnect=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC


spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

This is the error:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:526) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1677) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1601) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:633) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:347) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:219) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:718) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:650) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:468) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.5.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:361) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) [spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) [spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) [spring-orm-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at 
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at be.weby.api.Main.main(Main.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 73
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.Buffer.readInteger(Buffer.java:271) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaCapabilities.setInitialHandshakePacket(MysqlaCapabilities.java:62) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.readServerCapabilities(MysqlaProtocol.java:482) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.beforeHandshake(MysqlaProtocol.java:367) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.connect(MysqlaProtocol.java:1412) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:132) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:1619) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]
... 44 common frames omitted
```

As you can see, I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. I have no idea what this is in this context. I tried different dialects like InnoDB, MySql5 et cetera, nothing works.

Help is very much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: are you able to access the db directly otherwise?

Comment: Is it maven project ? can you show dependencies you're using ?

Comment: what version of the server?

Comment: which all dialects did you use?

Comment: `mysql://159.65.200.68:3306/timYcreateDatabaseIfNotExist=true` ?? look to me thats the error should be more like `mysql://159.65.200.68:3306/[database]?[options]` so it should be more like `mysql://159.65.200.68:3306/timY?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` it's in the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

change your property for database url:-

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://159.65.200.68:3306/timY?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

point to be noted here is that db name is timY :-) and add your properties like you have mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Changed the MySQL version from 6 to 5. Got a clear message then. Apparently the user didn't allow foreign hosts so I configured the mySql server. After this I changed back to 6.0.5 and everything works fine.